# elasticsearch query filter "or" with wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I try to use elasticsearch to make a query with wildcard (the use of *) for an autocomplete function.

It was working good with `bool query` like this (where value can contain *) :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": value
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

But now I want to search only an input value in some fields ( `T_FAMILY` or `T_GENUS` or `T_SCIENTIFICNAME`) and use wildcards $ and *:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "T_FAMILY",
    "T_GENUS",
    "T_SCIENTIFICNAME"
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "T_FAMILY": value
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "T_GENUS": value
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "T_SCIENTIFICNAME": value
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the query work but the wildcards don't.
I can't find why.
The 3 fields are `analyzed` in the mapping.

Comment: where do you use the wildcards? not present in the code fragment.

Comment: sorry. the value is a user input and can contain the wildcard.
for exemple with value = 'abama' the query work but when i try value = 'abam*' it doesnt with filtered. ( it work with query_string)

Comment: replace "term" elements with query_string then? or you can also have AND and OR in query_string itself.

Comment: thank you @Ashalynd, i try this and it work far better :
......
"query" : {
               "query_string" : { "query" : "T_FAMILY:" +val +" or T_GENUS:"+val+ " or T_SCIENTIFICNAME:"+val} }
.....              
Does the wildcard work even if the field is mapped "not_analysed" ?